# Symbian mobile os - how to write C applications?

Tags: c, mobile, symbian, mobile-phones

I want to write a C application that runs on Symbian mobile OS. I don't know where to start.
Is there any library files available or any SDK or IDE available for it?

Comment: Go to http://www.google.com.

Enter "Symbian SDK" in the search box.

Comment: I "improved" spelling and grammar, but I'm not sure this question is narrow enough in focus to stand. I'll let it stew for a while before voting to close, to see if it gains some focus or has an answer more interesting than "let me google that for you".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_do_I_start_programming_for_Symbian_OS%3F

[Architecture http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/images/9/95/OpenCppEnv.png](http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/images/9/95/OpenCppEnv.png):

Developer community tutorial [link](http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/index.php/Category:C/C%2B%2B).

Answer (score 2):

Just like to elaborate on the previous post. Symbian supports POSIX libraries via [Open C](http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/index.php/Open_C_and_Open_C%2B%2B_Quick_Start). Mobile apps almost always have a UI. Depending on your objective, you might check out Qt on Symbian too.

-hth
John

Comment: How does Qt help with writing an application in C?

Comment: When we write a program, we want to solve a problem. The original question does explicit say in C. I am simply suggesting a UI is a natural next step. C and C++ work well together. Allow the original author to access/reuse the C APIs and leverage Qt's UI and application framework.

Answer (score 1):

You should download the Nokia Qt SDK (http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/) . This allows you to write applications in C/C++ (without having to learn the Symbian flavor of C++).